# purchase a downloadable product as guest checkout it does not appear in my downloadable products section

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

When I purchase a downloadable product as a guest and create account after that. The downloadable products  does not appear in the my downloadable products section after completed purchase but invoice is appear in My Orders.

I got an answer that the fix for this issue has already available in 2.2-develop branch.
Where I can get that.

My magento ver is 2.2.6

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/33385380/45645670-32319500-ba8f-11e8-8966-0979b54273e7.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You may consider patching the core file, by rolling the changes in `\Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement::savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder`  from following commit back, as I did in my case.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e76430179fd9679f448883d05be40ae5423dd067?diff=unified#commitcomment-30923778

This issue is present since magento 2.2.4